# After Login waring error You are not authorised to view this resource

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, error-handling, error-pages, php7

I am getting warning error when user logged in. After logged in on top of header show warning message "You are not authorised to view this resource." And when try to download  attachment it's  showing error page "file does not exist".
Any Help

Comment: Please could you explain in more detail what the problem is. What version of Joomla? What extension? Are you sure you've setup the correct permissions for this file?

Comment: Lodder@ I got solution

Answer (score 1):

I have Resolved this issue this is very basic solution .

```
1. You must have to give permissions public to all special and register menu.
2:You must have to give permissions public to all special and register content .
```

After This .warning error Resolved